# How would I change the nickname of a user with a message in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to change a user's nickname in Discord.js v12, yet for some reason I get the error:

`TypeError: fn is not a function`

Here is my code:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.find(message.author.id).setNickname(username)
```

The `message` is just a `Message` object from a `.on("message")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `.get()`, [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) accepts a function, so you can use it like this:

```js
message.guild.members.cache
  .find(member => member.id === message.author.id)
  .setNickname()
```

You could also use [`.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=get):

```js
message.guild.members.cache
  .get(message.author.id)
  .setNickname()
```

Or even better, use [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```js
message.guild.members.fetch(message.author.id)
  .then(member => member.setNickname())
```

Or, you can get the member from the message itself using the [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) property that represents the author of the message as a guild member:

```js
message.member.setNickName()
```